# How do I use the "If" statement to compare two conditions?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False

Test = "C10"
Test1 = "C11"

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(Test1)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value2 = "No" Then
        Range(Test).ClearContents
    ElseIf Target.Value2 = "Yes" Then
        Sheets("Calculator").Range(Test).Value = "Hello World"
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

How do I use the "If" statement to compare two conditions? Something like this:

```
If Target.Value2 = "No" And Test="Apple" Then
```

Comment: Try, `If Target.Value2 = "No" And range(Test) = "Apple" Then` but there are a number of problem areas in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Target` could be one or more cells that were changed at once (for example, multiple could be changed at once when pasting a range of cells).

It looks like you're expecting a single cell to be changed since you're checking if `Target` has a single value, which is fine - but if that's the case,you won't need `Intersect` (that would be for checking if your cell was within a *range* of cells).

I'm not clear on your intention but this is my interpretation of what you're trying to do:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Test As String, Test1 As String     'declare variables
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Test = "C10"
    Test1 = "C11"

    If Target.Address = Test1 Then 'if C11 is the cell that was changed then...
        If Target = "No" Then               '( if C11 = "No" then...             )
            Range(Test).ClearContents       '( erase whatever's in cell C10      )
        ElseIf Target = "Yes" Then          '( otherwise, if C11 = "Yes" then... )
            Range(Test) = "Hello World"     '( make C10 = "Hello World".         )
        End If
    End If                 ' if a cell other than C10 was changed, or C11 contains
                           '  anything except "Yes" or "No", then do nothing.

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

- `Value` is optional and unnecessary since it's the default property for most objects.
- Although it's a good idea to specify exact location of your objects (to "fully qualify" them) it's redundant in this case since this procedure will only be called by the one worksheet
  where the code is placed, which I am assuming is called `Calculator`.
- As mentioned above, `Intersect` seems unnecessary in this case.  If indeed want to check if `Target` is within a range of cells (like if `B2` was within `A1:C3`, which it is), you could use something like: 
  `If Intersect(Target,Range("A1:C3") then ...`

You could experiment with this sub in the worksheet's module to see how changes are interpreted by Excel:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "Number of cells changed: " & Target.Cells.Count & vbLf & _
           "Changed cell(s): " & Target.Address & vbLf & _
           "Cell value changed to: " & _
                IIf(Target.Cells.Count > 1, "(Multiple values)", Target)
End Sub
```

Comment: Agree it's not necessary, but I think it's a good habit to get into to explicitly stating properties etc, particularly if you're learning (and sometimes you do need to explicitly use `Value`). Also not sure you can assume it is the `Calculator` sheet as seems odd that it's only referred to in one line. Lastly, you need to change `Test1` or use `Target.Address(0,0)`.

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks for the comments. I will test it out.  My sample code was just something I came up to show my issue... sorry it is not very complete as I am new to this Excel VBA stuff.